# jQuery 1.5.2: default variable not modifyable within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

First of all I'm not sure if I stated the subject of my question very well.

I am trying to set a default variable "var x" at the beginning of my script, which I want to modify later on. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = false;
    $('elem').live('click', function(){
        x = true;
        $('form').trigger('submit');
    });
    $('form').submit(function(){
        if (x == false) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Using jQuery 1.4.2 this seems to work, 'x' appears to be true and the form submits. But now I'm using 1.5.2 and it doesn't seem to work this way anymore. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Is it because the var x = false; will always reset the variable's value to false?

Thanks

Comment: What about the current jquery?

Comment: I will try it with the current jquery, however I may not use it jet as the rest of the website hasn't been tested with it // edit: same problem (1.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to repro, works perfectly fine in jQuery 1.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/BK2CH/3/

By the way I would recommend you using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to attach this state as metadata of the form instead of polluting your global scope with global variables. Just like that:

```
$('div').live('click', function() {
    $('form').data('x', true).trigger('submit');
});

$('form').submit(function(){
    var x = $(this).data('x');
    if (x) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```